# Why would the child theme load in the Customize preview, but not on the site itself?

Tags: php, css, child-theme, theme-customizer, wp-enqueue-style

I have my child theme folder, the style.css sheet with the required template comment and some custom css, and I have the functions.php page with the [required enqueing code](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Everything seems to be in order, except that my custom css is not reflected on my website. However, it *IS* reflected in the Wordpress Customize screen. Why would this be the case, and how would I get my site to display the custom CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work correctly now, I do not know why emptying the cache didn't work before to allow the changes to show but it seems to work correctly now.